# Primary Links Not Showing Up On Certain Themes

Tags: 7, theming

In Drupal 7, I have a page in the Primary links menu. I set the page content type to use the primary links. In Garland I can see the item at the top of the page, but in a bunch of other themes I can't, like AT Adaptive, Fusion, and Sky. What gives? How do I get the primary links to show up in those themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to show primary links: through the theme settings or through a block placement. Check your theme's settings to see if it has a setting for display of primary links. If it does not, your only configuration option is to place the primary links block into a region through block administration.

Comment: That did the trick. What confused me is that some of the themes have that block enabled.